# Haproxy close connections to backup hosts when primary comes back

Tags: tcp, load-balancing, publish-subscribe, failover, haproxy

### Question

Can I get haproxy to close all connections to backup hosts when a primary host becomes available after being down?

### Context

I am using HAproxy to do failover for pubsub.

The haproxy backend config looks something like this:

```
listen pubsub 0.0.0.0:1234
    mode tcp

    server primary primary.x.com:1234 weight 1 inter 500 rise 10 fall 5 check
    server backup backup.x.com:1234 weight 1 inter 500 rise 10 fall 5 check backup
```

I make long lived connections for both the publish and the subscribe sides.

the problem is in the scenario that:

- `primary` goes down
- `A` connects to `backup` and publishes
- `B` connects to `backup` and subscribes
- `primary` is fixed and becomes alive again
- `C` connects to `primary` and publishes **but `B` does not receive it**
- `D` connects to `primary` and subscribes **but does not get `A`'s messages**

The best solution to this problem that I can see is to have haproxy forcibly close all connections to backup hosts when a primary becomes available again.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an older question, and you've probably found a solution by now, but if you haven't then I think the answer you are looking for is the [on-marked-up](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#5.2-on-marked-up) server option. This is a new server option as of version 1.5.

According to the documentation, you can provide an action to perform when a server is marked as "up". Currently, the only action is:

> shutdown-backup-sessions: Shutdown sessions on all backup servers...

```
server primary ... on-marked-up shutdown-backup-sessions
```